# K8s Service to all replicas

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks, kubernetes-service

I have a kubernetes cluster on which there are 2 different type of apps. I will call them A and B.

Each of these apps are replicated so that there are 2As and 2Bs.

Each A app needs to communicate with all Bs. I tried to create a Kubernetes Service, but obviously one A communicates with one B and the other A communicates with the other B.

Actually using Kubernetes Service for B:

[image: actual]

What I would like to have:

[image: desired]

Is there a way in Kubernetes to allow each A to communicate with ***all*** Bs without using IP addresses explicitly or splitting the Kubernetes Service for each B app?

Comment: Can't you just refer `service B` from your workload `A` so it points out to any pods behinds `service B`?

Comment: Unfortunately not. "A" needs each "B" IP. I would like to add an abstraction like a Service to avoid configuring things with IPs. If I would like to scale a bit, using IPs would be a mess...

Comment: Declare an `ingress` in front of `service B` and reference the declared hostname from workload `A` ?

Comment: What type of service did you try to create ? Any reason why each "A" needs to communitate with All "B" ? You have 2 instances of A, when a request comes to one of the instance it will communicate to B via service which will be received by either of "B". There isn't a direct one to one flow. 
You can read about service and proxy from https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service